# Combining TFPDF and AutoPrint

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to combine 2 different scripts

1. Autoprint - http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php
2. TFPDF - http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Each script is working on its own as expected but I want them to work together. I tried searching but there's no similar situation as what I am facing. I tried combining different classes as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429624/php-how-to-combine-these-two-classes) but couldn't get it to work.

This is what I tried:

```
require('fpdf/pdf_js.php');
require('fpdf/tfpdf.php');
class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_JavaScript
{
    function AutoPrint($printer='')
    {
        if($printer)
        {
            $printer = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $printer);
            $script = "var pp = getPrintParams();";
            $script .= "pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;";
            $script .= "pp.printerName = '$printer'";
            $script .= "print(pp);";
        }
        else
            $script = 'print(true);';
        $this->IncludeJS($script);
    }
}

$pdf = new tFPDF(new PDF_AutoPrint());
```

It is giving me this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDF_AutoPrint could not be converted to string
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the PDF_JavaScript class to extend tFPDF instead of FPDF. Then, change your last line to: `$pdf = new PDF_AutoPrint();`